# CSS - If width then split the text and on hover do something

Tags: css, split, mousehover

So I have this text

> Arabic, Brazilian, Dutch, English, French, German, Greek, Indonesian,
>   Malay, Norwegian, Romanian, Spanish, Swedish, Thai, Turkish,
>   Vietnamese

and I want do split it on 500px so when it display at first the

> Arabic, Brazilian, Dutch, English, French, German, Greek, Indonesian,
>   Malay will showing

and on hover

> Norwegian, Romanian, Spanish, Swedish, Thai, Turkish, Vietnamese will
>   display

please someone help me and with deferent text too just an example..please help me

Comment: jQuery could be really useful here.

Comment: Is word wrapping not enough for this?

Comment: We aren't here to write code for you. Try something yourself first. Put in some effort and do your research.

Answer (score 0):

Quick, dirty and untested:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper"><p class="contents">Arabic, Brazilian, [...]</p></div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.contents {
    position: absolute; 
}

.contents {
    top: 0px;
}

.contents:hover {
    bottom: 0px;
}
```